# Why it is mandatory to check the condition in wait_event after prepare_to_wait?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, blockingqueue

I am trying to understand how wait_event is implemented in linux kernel. There is a code example in ldd3 where the internal implementation is explained using prepare_to_wait (http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-6-sect-2).

```c
static int scull_getwritespace(struct scull_pipe *dev, struct file *filp)
{
    while (spacefree(dev) == 0) {
        DEFINE_WAIT(wait);

        up(&dev->sem);
        if (filp->f_flags & O_NONBLOCK)
            return -EAGAIN;
        PDEBUG("\"%s\" writing: going to sleep\n",current->comm);
        prepare_to_wait(&dev->outq, &wait, TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
        if (spacefree(dev) == 0)  // Why is this check necessary ??
            schedule(  );
        finish_wait(&dev->outq, &wait);
        if (signal_pending(current))
            return -ERESTARTSYS; /* signal: tell the fs layer to handle it */
        if (down_interruptible(&dev->sem))
            return -ERESTARTSYS;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the book, it is explained as below.

> Then comes the obligatory check on the buffer; we must handle the case
>   in which space becomes available in the buffer after we have entered
>   the while loop (and dropped the semaphore) but before we put ourselves
>   onto the wait queue. Without that check, if the reader processes were
>   able to completely empty the buffer in that time, we could miss the
>   only wakeup we would ever get and sleep forever. Having satisfied
>   ourselves that we must sleep, we can call schedule.

I am not able to understand this piece of explanation. How we would go to a indefinite sleep if the `if (spacefree(dev) == 0)` is not done before calling schedule() ?
if this obligatory check is not present, wakeup() still resets the process state to TASK_RUNNING and schedule returns as explained in the next paragraph.

> It is worth looking again at this case: what happens if the wakeup
>   happens between the test in the if statement and the call to schedule?
>   In that case, all is well. The wakeup resets the process state to
>   TASK_RUNNING and schedule returns—although not necessarily right away.
>   As long as the test happens after the process has put itself on the
>   wait queue and changed its state, things will work.

Answer (score 6):

The important thing is that the (last) check is done *after* `prepare_to_wait()` was called.

`prepare_to_wait()` puts a pointer to the current process into the wait queue. If the wakeup happens *before* the `prepare_to_wait()` call, the wakeup would not be able to affect the current process.

Comment: Ahh.. I got it now. Thanks for the explanation.